# Estimation of Focus of expansion

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to estimate focus of expansion for a moving camera mounted in a mobile robot. I am using the method described in [this](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~donovan/stabilization/opticalflow.pdf) method page 13-14. My aim is to use it to avoid obstacle using optical flow. I have attached the code below. Calculating the terms when I display the calculated point it keeps jumping around and isnt correct. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
void calculate_FOE(vector<Point2f> prev_pts, vector<Point2f> next_pts)

    MatrixXf A(next_pts.size(),2);
    MatrixXf b(next_pts.size(),1);
    Point2f tmp;

    for(int i=0;i<next_pts.size();i++)
    {

        tmp= prev_pts[i]-next_pts[i];
        A.row(i)<<prev_pts[i].x-next_pts[i].x,prev_pts[i].y-next_pts[i].y;
        b.row(i)<<(prev_pts[i].x*tmp.x)-(prev_pts[i].y*tmp.y);

    }


    Matrix<float,2,1> FOE;
    FOE=((A.transpose()*A).inverse())*A.transpose()*b;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focus of expansion (FOE) is the point in the image that has the smallest cross product with all of the optical flow vectors. Each optical flow vector has a previous point and a delta. Let $p_x$ and $p_y$ be the x and y positions of the previous position of an optical flow vector. Let $dx$ and $dy$ be the change in x and y position between the previous location and the current location.

The cross product between a single optical flow vector and the FOE is
\begin{equation}
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
p_x-foe_x & p_y - foe_y &0\\
dx & dy &0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
M = \hat k \left( (p_x - foe_x)dy - (p_y - foe_y)dx \right)
\end{equation}

The moment, $M$, is what we want to minimize. So setting $M$ equal to zero we can solve for the FOE.

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
-dy & dx \\
... & ... \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
foe_x \\ foe_y\\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_ydx-p_x dy \\
...\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Note that my matrices do not match the matrices in the paper; their $v$ term is positive while I believe it should be negative.

Comment: [This link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-perception/lecture/DgSNW/3d-velocities-from-optical-flow) provides an explanation of how focus of expansion can be computed from optical flow vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reversing your derivatives so that velocities are specified forward in time? i.e., do `next_pts - prev_pts` instead of `prev_pts - next_pts`. Negating all the constraint equations could result in the crazy instability you describe.

It also looks like `A.row(i)` can be simplified to just `tmp`.

If you haven't already, you should also try visualizing the optical flow results that are feeding into this estimation, to make sure that they look good enough for you, as a human, to identify FOE from them.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the results are same. I have attached a gif of the results if that helps.   https://gph.is/2pVTRI8